# Azure load balancer does not forward HTTPS requests to Servers

Tags: azure, load-balancing

I have 2 VMs behind a load balancer on Azure. I have enabled HTTPS connection for the Websites i have deployed in those VMs using self signed ssl certificate. When I connect to that VM directly via IP I see the certificate loaded, but when i try to connect through load balancer over HTTPS, I get a page which specified "Your connection is not private" (as it is self signed certificate) and in Advanced i click on "proceed to site". For VMs   it works, but when i use load balancer IP it will load the same page again and again specifying the same error. I couldn't find much material for implementing HTTPS as well. i implemented based on my understanding of Azure load balancer.

Also can i achieve HTTPS using load balancer or do i need to implement Application Gateway?

Privacy Error:

[image: Error in Browser]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Azure CLI to create an [application gateway](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview) with a certificate for SSL termination that uses a virtual machine scale set for backend servers. In this example, the scale set contains two virtual machine instances that are added to the default backend pool of the application gateway.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-ssl-cli

Comment: Does this mean i cannot create using load balancer?

Comment: Azure Load Balancer is a layer 4 service, it works with all UDP and TCP protocols .  App Gateway is a Layer 7 service that can provide SSL offload (this can't be done at layer 4).  See our docs for details on the different load balancing services in Azure. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-load-balancing-azure

Comment: Thanks. I have one last doubt. In my current implementation  i have installed self signed certificate on my VMs. In load balancer i configured port 443 having HTTPS health Probe. I am getting Privacy Error as it is self signed certificate. If i have a proper certificate signed by certificate authority, wont it work?

Comment: @VGanesh You can use Standard Load Balancer for your requirement. However you will not get SSL termination capabilities in layer 4 azure load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

The certificates must match the IP address of the listener of the load balancer, that is the IP address seen by the clients. You must autocertificate the IP of the load balancer and deploy this certificate in all the balanced sites, and this certificate only works if you access through the load balancer then.